How to open the Manage Unused Data window using python code?
I'm new to Blender python. I would like to open the "Managed Unused Data" Window by using a button. Why is the function below not working? I've already added a button that can execute the class, but nothing happen. If I use the main menu in blender, all works and the window opens. I took the phyton code from there ( bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_manage() ) . Why is it impossible to open the window in my snippet?
Any help? Here's my snippet:
# Manage Orphan Data
class CWTools_PurgeDataManager(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.cw_tools_purgedatamanager"
    bl_label = "Manage Purged Data"
    bl_description = "Manage all unused data"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_manage()
        return {'FINISHED'}

This is the window I would like to open with the code above.


After a bit of trial&error I found that you must call the operator with the special INVOKE_AREA parameter.
import bpy
bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_manage("INVOKE_AREA")

Link to the docs
BTW you don't have to define an override operator if you just want to open this window in your custom operator execute. You can force the operator context inside your layout. Just bear in mind the entire layout will have this context. You can set it back to exec default afterwards.
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_AREA'

    layout.operator("outliner.orphans_manage")
    
    layout.operator_context = 'EXEC_DEFAULT' # Back to "normal"

# Alternatively :
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator_context = 'INVOKE_AREA'
    row.operator("outliner.orphans_manage")
    # layout.operator_context is untouched


Thank you a lot. The "INVOKE_AREA" option was the solution. Works great!
